# Specifying resource group name when creating resource group in aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm trying to figure out how to specify a resource group name when creating resource groups via aws cli, when I look at the cli documentation for [create-resource-group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/inspector/create-resource-group.html) command I only see option to specify tags, how do you specify a name? , also I noticed when I access the console I don't see resource groups created using cli. Any ideas?

Comment: I guess using AWS CLI for resource group you can only create tags because I checked this same 2-3 weeks back and did not find any resource or guide for naming resource group.

Comment: looks like the resource group created using the cli command is used for creating Inspector assessment target, not sure if they are the same.

Comment: So It looks like you have to use the tag editor to search resources that are tagged with specific key/value then you can view as resource group and save. Doesn’t look like you can do this in cli. So if you are provisioning resources via cli and you want to leverage resource group you just simply tag resources when provisioning them and use the tag editor in aws console to find resources and view as resource group and save.